# What does "run for" mean?

Tags: meaning, quotations

> "I ran for Congress, just once."
>
> -- Shirley Temple

What does "run for" mean? What does this quote mean?

Comment: You could have looked it up [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+run+for+an+office)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Run for Office* is a quote you will hear more and more of as we get closer to November.

To *run for ABC* is to nominate yourself, or accept the nomination from a party, to fill a political position. After being nominated, you then *campaign* until a preset date when the people cast their votes. The candidate with the most votes wins the position.

*Run for* is also a phrase that means "persist for a specified period of time."

> I can *run for* two hours without stopping.

Both examples speak to perseverance. It is no easy feat campaigning for public office - it takes willpower, dedication and a little luck as well.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Shirley Temple competed in an election as a candidate for a Congress member, just once.

Apart from the above sense of the phrase "run for", it is also used to mean to last or continue for a particular period, for example, "The film runs for three hours".